# Hitchin map and vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

I've been learning a bit about automorphisms of moduli spaces of vector bundles and the Hitchin map.
I'm reading [this paper of Indranil Biswas, Tomas L. Gomez, V. Munoz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2961), and I have a problem about prop $5.1$

Let $E$ be a semistable vector bundle over a smooth projective curve $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $K_X$ be the canonical bundle of $X$.

$H$ is the Hitchin map, $H:H^0(End_0E\otimes K_X)\rightarrow W$  $(W:=\bigoplus H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes i}))$
and $h_r$ is the composition of $H$ and the projection $W\rightarrow W_r$  $(W_r:=H^0(X,K_X^{\otimes r}))$
$h_r:H^0(End_0E\otimes K_X)\rightarrow W_r$

Then prop $5.1$ says that 
$H^0(End_0E\otimes K_X(-x))$$=\{\psi\in H^0(End_0E\otimes K_X) \mid h_r(\psi+\phi)\in H^0(K_X^{\otimes r }(-x)),\forall\phi \in h_r^{-1}(H^0(K_X^{\otimes r}{(-x)}))\}$
By using prop$5.1$, we can get the vector bundle
$\mathcal{E}\rightarrow X$
whose fiber over $x \in X$ is $\mathcal{E}_x=H^0(End_0E\otimes K_X(-x))$

But I don't understand why prop$5.1$ allows us to construct such vector bundle.It shows that $dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{E}_{x}$ is constant?

This may be a stupid question.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Let $F=End_0 E \otimes K_X$, let $p,q:X\times X\to X$ be the projections, and let $\Delta\subseteq X\times X$ be the diagonal. Isn’t $p_*(\mathcal{O}(-\Delta)\otimes q^* F)$ the bundle you want?

Comment: The “constant dimension” condition + Grauert’s theorem (cohomology and base change) will tell you that it is locally free with formation compatible with base change (so the fibers are what you want).

Comment: Thanks for comments. I think what you are saying is right and it is very helpful. But how does your comment relate to the proposition 5.1 ?